# Canvas in Unity3D is automatically duplicating when Application.LoadLevel is called

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is the strangest of issues. We call Application.LoadLevel to reload the current level when the player gets out. What we noticed is that the canvas count doubles each time we call LoadLevel.
The game starts with 1 canvas, player gets out we call LoadLevel and then have 2 canvas. Player gets out again, we call LoadLevel and now we have 4 canvases. This continues and continues.

I can't figure out what is causing this to happen.

Any idea?

Comment: This is not some side effect of some script saving all the canvases in the scene and restoring them? And you are doing `LoadLevel()`, not `LoadLevelAdditive()`? Could you maybe post the line of code in which you load the scene, and maybe a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: I don't store any canvases. We call Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);

Comment: I cannot explain the exponential growth in the form of `2^n`, after loading the level `n` times. One thing that would make sense is, if you used the `DontDestroyOnLoad()` function on the canvas, it wouldn't be destroyed (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html); but then, the number of canvases would only increase linearly. Can you upload a minium, complete and verifiable example?

Comment: Ah ha! You got it. There is a DontDestroyOnLoad script on the Canvas which was being used for Admob. I removed the script and now it no longer duplicates.
Now I need to figure out how to handle the Admob...
Thanks for your help! BTW - you should put your suggestion in as an answer so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Followup from the comments)

I cannot explain the exponential growth in the form of `2^n`, after loading the level `n` times. One thing that would make sense is, if you used the `DontDestroyOnLoad()` function on the canvas, it wouldn't be destroyed (docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html); but then, the number of canvases would only increase linearly. Check the scripts for calls on that function.